# Why do the changes (to CSS properties) caused by JQuery event handler appear only momentarily?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/6e4buwbn/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var numberOfItems = $('.item').length;

  if (numberOfItems > 4) {
    $('.wrapper').mouseover(function() {
      $('a.next-arrow').css('display', 'block');
    });
    $('.wrapper').mouseleave(function() {
      $('a.next-arrow').css('display', 'none');
    });
  }

  /**
  *
  **/
  $('a.next-arrow').click(function() {
    var i = 1;
    while (i <= numberOfItems) { //1, 5
      if ($('div.item' + i).css('display').toLowerCase() == 'inline-block') {

        $('div.item' + i).css('display', 'none');
        
        break;
      }

      i = i + 4;
    }
    
  });
  
  
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px none;
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.item {
  /*position:absolute;*/
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25vw;
}
.wheat {
  background-color: wheat;
}
.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}
.beige {
  background-color: beige;
}
.gainsboro {
  background-color: gainsboro;
}
.coral {
  background-color: coral;
}
.crimson {
  background-color: crimson;
}
.item1 {
  left: 0%;
}
.item2 {
  left: 25%;
}
.item3 {
  left: 50%;
}
.item4 {
  left: 75%;
}
.item5 {
  left: 100%;
}
.item6 {
  left: 125%;
}
.previous-arrow,
.next-arrow {
  width: 30px;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.7;
  /*color: transparent;*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: -30px;
  display: none;
}
.previous-arrow {
  background-image: url(a2.png);
  left: 0px;
}
.next-arrow {
  background-image: url(b2.png);
  right: 0px;
}
.previous-arrow,
.next-arrow {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="previous-arrow" href="">&lt;</a><!--
  --><div class="item item1 wheat">a.</div><!--
  --><div class="item item2 pink">a.</div><!--
  --><div class="item item3 beige">a.</div><!--
  --><div class="item item4 gainsboro">a.</div><!--
  --><div class="item item5 coral">a.</div><!--
  --><div class="item item6 crimson">a.</div><!--
  --><a class="next-arrow" href="">&lt;</a>
</div>
```

In this SSCCE, I want to use the JQuery to handle the click event on `.next-arrow`, and in the handler, I want to hide the `.item1` (for this example - I have over-simplified to demonstrate my problem). When it is hidden, the .`item5` should will into the screen (which was previously overflowed out of the screen).

That does happen, but then:

1. In the code snippet in SO editor, which can be seen above, it shows only momentarily and then the screen goes blank.
2. In JSFiddle, linked above, as well as on my computer, it appears only momentarily and then the screen goes back to its initial appearance, that is the `.item1` appears again, making the `.item4` overflow out of the screen.

I have tried and failed to figure out what is happening. **Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Not sure if I understand you question correctly, but I guess the problem you have is that the click on the `a` (the arrow) also reloads the page. To solve that you would need to either use something else then `a` or prevent the default behaviour. [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6e4buwbn/1/)

Comment: Your page is been reloaded!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need to prevent the default action of clicking the link (currently it reloads the page).

Pass `event` (You can use any name) to your function, and use [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

```
$('a.next-arrow').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // etc
```